# Is there better way to get UICollectionViewFlowLayout attributes without inheriting

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have

```
class MyCollectionViewLayoutA: UICollectionViewFlowLayout
class MyCollectionViewLayoutB: UICollectionViewFlowLayout
```

So I wanted to add a function to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to get its original layout attributes.

I knew it could be done with a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, but is there any better way to do this?

I have tried to make it with an extension, but `super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)` will return `nil` while `self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)` will call its subclass implementation.

I also try to make a protocol with a extension to have default implementation, but `self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)` will also call its subclass implementation and **super can not be used outside class members**.

Here is my code:

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    func originalLayoutAttributes() -> [Int: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]? {
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return nil }
        let numberOfSections = collectionView.numberOfSections
        if numberOfSections <= 0 {
            return nil
        }

        var sectionItemAttributes = [Int: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()
        for section in 0 ..< numberOfSections {
            var attributesArray = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
            for index in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: section)
                var itemAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
                itemAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
                //itemAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
                attributesArray.append(itemAttributes)
            }
            sectionItemAttributes[section] = attributesArray.isEmpty ? nil : attributesArray
        }
        return sectionItemAttributes.isEmpty ? nil : sectionItemAttributes
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got it?  Why not get the size instead?

Comment: @dengApro No, it is still unsolved, what do you mean by "size"? I want to make a customized layout, the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes ` is necessary.